# Manually deleting expired documents

Tags: mongodb

I know that mongod every 60 seconds starts automatically deleting expired docs. Is there a way to start manually deleting expired documents? Or to set another time?

Comment: What do u mean by `mongod` every 60 seconds starts automatically deleting expired docs? **Manually:** Filter the documents expired (based on date or other criteria) and use `delete({}), deleteMany({})`. **Set another time:** I am guessing u are looking for [TTL indexes on clock time](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time) with `expireAfterSeconds : 0`

Comment: mongod is the primary daemon process for the MongoDB system. A background thread in mongod reads the values in the index and removes expired documents from the collection. The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. I want to run it manually or set up another time.

Comment: yeah ok that's the default behaviour with ttl indexes. Is `expireAfterSeconds : 0` and defining a time(for expiration) on a field, not what u are looking for?